# Changing yii default username field to email field for login

Tags: php, mysql, email, yii

To login in yii, i want to do it on a database table (mysql) instead of the default "admin" and "demo" default values provided in the UserIdentity class. The thing is, my user table in the database that i created does not use username and password fields for authentication, but rather email and password fields. So when i change all the "username" to "email" variables in UserIdentity.php, LoginForm.php, SiteController.php, login.php, i get an error:

Property "UserIdentity.email" is not defined.

and the error points to the change i made here by replacing username with email as shown below:

```
public function authenticate()
    {

    $user = User::model()->findByAttributes(array(
             'email' => $this->email
    ));
```

Help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may change email on login in UserIdentity.

```
$user = User::model()->findByAttributes(array(
     'email' => $this->username
));
```

Or add new field 'email' to UserIdentity and use it.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I used ..'email' => $this->username and it worked also.

Comment: Hi @Alex, changing the core file 'UserIdentity' isn't a bad practice?

Comment: @Pupil I mean you will extend your own Identify from UserIdentity